Comparing agent decision-making under risk-neutrality and risk-Aversion
I am working on the following question but have not been able to come up with a suitable way to proceed. The setup is as follows:
There is a technology (for example, a vaccine) which reduces the probability of the occurrence of a bad state. The probability of the bad state before and after adoption is 'p' and 'q', respectively. The agent's utility function is given by h(x). The agent gets a utility 'u' from adoption. If the bad state occurs, irrespective of the adoption decision, there is a dis-utility of '-f'.
For a risk-neutral agent with h(x) = x. The expected utility from adoption is
$$U(\text{adopt})=q(u-f)+(1-q)(u),$$
whereas the expected utility of not adopting is
$$U(\text{not adopt})=p\cdot (-f).$$
When we compare the to utilities, the agent adopts if,
$$q(u-f) + (1-q)\cdot u>p\cdot (-f)$$ which implies that the agent adopts if $$u/f>(q-p).$$ The RHS gives us a threshold.
For a risk-averse agent, with utility given by $h(x)$, the utility from adoption is
$$U(\text{adopt}) = q\cdot h(u-f)+(1-q)\cdot h(u),$$ whereas the utility of not adopting is,
$$U(\text{not adopt}) = p\cdot h(-f).$$ This does not give us a threshold as we have not specified the function $h(x)$.
My question is as follows: how can I compare the threshold of the agent for the two preference types (even though I have not specified $h(x)$)? Is there a way that I can say with certainty that the threshold for a risk-averse agent is lower/higher than that of a risk-neutral agent? If so, how do you prove that the threshold for the risk-averse agent is lower/higher than that of a risk-neutral agent?

I think in the risk averse case $U(\text{not adopt}) = p\cdot h(-f)$ should be $$U(\text{not adopt}) = p\cdot h(-f) + (1-p)\cdot h(0).$$ Also, are you familiar with the connection between concavitiy of $h$ and risk aversion?

Dear @Giskard, thank you for your comment. I should have mentioned that I assume that $h(0)=0$. Yes, I am familiar with the connection between the concavity of $h$ and risk aversion. A risk-averse agent has a concave function, where $$h((1-\alpha)x+\alpha y) \geq (1-\alpha)h(x) + \alpha h(y)$$
